# How do I match multiple arguments?

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

I have a function:

```
def func(a: int, b: int, c: double): int
```

And I want to match various possible scenarios

1. Wherever `c` is 0, return `b-a`
2. Wherever `c` > 9, return 0
3. Wherever `a=b` return 0

And so on, before doing some more complex logic if none of the above are satisfied.

Do I have to match c separately first, or can I match on a,b,c, like `_,_,0`?

Answer (score 80, accepted):

You can pattern match all described cases like this:

```
def func(a: Int, b: Int, c: Double) = (a, b, c) match {
    case (a, b, 0) => b - a
    case (a, b, c) if c > 9 || a == b => 0
    case _ => 1 // add your logic here
}
```

Comment: This does indeed answer the question as posed, but why use patten matching here? It seems a case where the good old if statement works just fine..

Comment: @Paul if you have many conditions, each with an action to take, and of which a single condition will be matched, then that's what pattern matching was made for. See Lisp's `cond`.

Comment: @Paul: To make long story short - it makes code more declarative IMHO. I like declarative code and programming in general. I saw in many other languages features, that allow them make pattern match (like above) directly in argument list - you can find it in Haskell, Clojure, Prolog for example. I wanted the same feature in Scala until I realized, that we already have it, but in other form (example is in  my answer). I find this form very useful - it makes my code more expressive, easy to understand and maintain (IMHO).

Comment: I'm not arguing that pattern matching isn't valuable anywhere. I am arguing that here it doesn't help make things clearer - mostly because all values used by any condition need to be in the expression matched (and Lisp's COND is not pattern matching, it's just if elseif else in a different wrapper. Here I would claim if/else if / else if / else is clearer - and more like COND)

Comment: Also, pattern matching (in Scala) introduces unnecessary overhead when if whould be sufficient (i.e. the calls to `unapply`).

Answer (score 5):

Following on from my comments to Easy Angel's answer, I still feel this

```
if (c == 0)
   b -a
else if (c > 9)
   0
else if (a == b)
   0
else 
   1 // your logic here
```

is clearer. Basically because there isn't really any pattern to match here.

Comment: Not sure why this gets downvotes, but downvote (or upvote) away, I've not changed my opinion